# coerce class data type in R with as

Tags: r, class, object, syntax, coercion

I understand that in R you have some base data types (`vector, matrix, list, data.frame`) and then in the R packages you have some advanced types called S3-class or S4-class (`ppp`,`owin`, `spatialPointsDataFrame` and many others. Some of the functions in R packages only work with arguments of special type.

I need explanation about converting between different classes and data types in R:

Sometimes I can use a code like:

```
m = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
df = as.data.frame(m)
```

But in other cases I must use a code like:

```
shp = readShapeSpatial("polygons.shp")
win = as(shp,"owin")
```

How do I know which syntax of the `as` to use for which object?
Or is the syntax: `as.foo(originalObject)` always equivalent to `as(originalObject, "foo")` (here foo stands for the class that I want to convert my object to so that I can use in a function that requires its argument to be a `foo` class)

Let's say I use a package in R with a class `foo`. And I have a variable `v` that belongs to class `bar` (in other words, `class(v)` is `bar`). How do I know if the function `as(v,"foo")` will work?

Comment: Start here to get a better grasp on classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583265/what-does-s3-methods-mean-in-r

Comment: You'll know if `as(v,"bar")` will work if you see an entry reading `from="foo", to="bar"` in the results printed by `showMethods("coerce")`. Or check whether `getMethod(coerce, signature=c(from="bar", to="foo"))` returns a function. Or just run `as(v, "bar")` to see if it works ;).

Comment: (Got a few of those `foo`'s and `bar`'s backwards, but you get the point.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as.data.frame` is an S3 method that you can check for `foo` using :

```
getS3method('as.data.frame','foo')
```

But I think you are looking for ( as it is commented)

```
showMethods(coerce)
```

This will give you a list of predefined coerce funsctions.

To define you coerce function , one option (there are many options like `setIS` , `coerce<-` and implicit coercion through inheritance) is to use `setAs`. Here an example:

```
track <- setClass("track",
                  slots = c(x="numeric", y="numeric"))
setAs("track", "numeric", function(from) from@y)
t1 <- new("track", x=1:20, y=(1:20)^2)
as(t1, "numeric")
```

Now if I check using :

```
showMethods(coerce)
```

You get an entry with :

```
from="track", to="numeric"
```

For better explanation you should read **help("as")** but the subject is not very simple.

**EDIT** To show only the entries with track you can do this for example:

```
cat(grep('track',showMethods(coerce,printTo=FALSE),value=TRUE))
from="track", to="numeric"
```

Comment: `showMethods(coerce)` is almost what I'm looking for. The only disadvantage is that the list is very long. Is there a way to show only the entries from `showMethods(coerce)` that contain `to="bar"`?

Comment: @jirikadlec2 you can see my edit. basically I filter the showMethods output.