# Write custom classifier in R and predict function

Tags: r, function, machine-learning, classification

I would like to implement my own custom classifier in R, e.g., **myClassifier(trainingSet, ...)** which returns the learnt model **m** from a specified training set. I would like to call it just like any other classifier in r:

```
m <- myClassifier(trainingSet)
```

and then I want to *overload* (I don't know if this is the correct word) the generic function **predict()**

```
result <- predict(m, myNewData)
```

I have just a basic knowledge in R. I don't know which resources I should read in order to accomplish the desired task. In order for this to work, do I need to create a package?. I am looking for some initial directions.

Does the model **m** contain information about the overriden predict method?, or how does R knows which predict.* method corresponds to model **m**?

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583265/what-does-s3-methods-mean-in-r) help

Comment: Or http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html has a bit more info.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is some code that shows how to write a method for your own class for a generic function.

```
# create a function that returns an object of class myClassifierClass
myClassifier = function(trainingData, ...) {
  model = structure(list(x = trainingData[, -1], y = trainingData[, 1]), 
                    class = "myClassifierClass") 
  return(model)
}

# create a method for function print for class myClassifierClass
predict.myClassifierClass = function(modelObject) {
  return(rlogis(length(modelObject$y)))
} 

# test
mA = matrix(rnorm(100*10), nrow = 100, ncol = 10)
modelA = myClassifier(mA)
predict(modelA)
```