# Understanding do.call semantics based on "plot"

Tags: r, do.call

I'm fooling around with `do.call`.

```
I = iris
do.call(what = "plot", args = c(I$Sepal.Length ~ I$Sepal.Width))
# This seems fine

p = list(x = I$Sepal.Length, y = I$Sepal.Width)
do.call(what = "plot", args = p)
# This looks weird

p1 = list(x = I$Sepal.Length, y = I$Sepal.Width, xlab = "")
do.call(what = "plot", args = p1)
# A bit less weird


p2 = list(x = I$Sepal.Length, y = I$Sepal.Width, xlab = "", ylab = "")
do.call(what = "plot", args = p2)
# And this gives the same as the first do.call
```

So why is it, that I have to supply the axis labels to surpress all those numbers I get when using `do.call` ?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi That should be `!=`. The former invokes `plot.formula`, the latter `plot.default`. That's why axis labels differ.

Comment: No, they refer to the axis labels. I doubt they've even noticed the issue of switching x and y.

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is what R puts on the axis labels when it can't get any other naming info from the arguments. If you do:

```
plot(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),y=c(1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4))
```

then the plot will have to use the vector values as the axis labels.

When using `do.call`, the names in the list arguments are matched to the names of the arguments of the function called. So there's no names left for the axis labels, just the values. At that point the fact that the data came from `I$Sepal.width` is long gone, its just a vector of values.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to understand that `plot` is an [S3 generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6583265/1412059) that calls methods depending on the first parameter. If you do `plot(y ~ x)` this method is `plot.formula` and axis labels are inferred from the formula. If you do `plot(x, y)` (note the different order of x and y), the method is `plot.default` and axis labels are inferred from the symbols passed as parameters.

Now, if you do `a <- 1:2; y <- 3:4; plot(x = a, y = b)`, the labels are `a` and `b`. However, if you use the `do.call` magic, `do.call(plot, list(x = a, y = b)` gets expanded to `plot(x = 1:2, y = 3:4)` and thus the labels are `1:2` and `3:4`. I'd recommend using the formula method with the `data` parameter, i.e., for your example:

```
do.call(what = "plot", args = list(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,
                                   data = I))
```