# Can't predict in ordinal::predict.clm(): cannot find function

Tags: r, ordinal

I have an ordinal model created using clmm() and I am trying to predict for a logistic regression. The function predict() does not work, so I am attempting predict.clm() but get this error:

```
Error in predict.clm() : could not find function "predict.clm"
```

Any help would be appreciated. The package is updated, R and Rstudio are both updated, and the package is loaded to Rstudio. I am new to R and am not sure how I would go about fixing this or otherwise go about predicting variables for my model.

I am wondering if I should go about changing my model to use the function polr() in package MASS as predict() does not work for the function clmm() which is what my model currently uses. Thank you in advance.

ETA: example, an behavior dataset

```
Proximity <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1) #ordinal variable
Treatment <- c("control", "control", "control", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "unfamiliar", "unfamiliar", "unfamiliar") #categorical
Event <- c("L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I") #categorical
Temperature <- c(70, 72, 72, 69, 79, 60, 63, 70, 74, 65) #numerical

#I also have nested random effects but have not included them for simplicity

Prox <- data.frame(Proximity, Treatment, Event, Temperature)

pro.1 <- clmm(Proximity ~ Treatment + Event + Temperature)  

predict.clm(pro.1, Prox) #this is where I get the error
```

Comment: did you try with predict(model, type = "class") ?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample? Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added a reproducible sample and I attempted type "class", I got the exact same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Normally calling `predict` should be sufficient. This should automatically call the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6583639/6574038) `predict.clm`.

However, `?ordinal::clmm` states:

> *This is a [...] improved implementation of CLMMs. The old implementation is available in clmm2. Some features are not yet
>   available in clmm [...].*

I suggest this is either not implemented or it is a bug. You could try `clmm2` alternatively. *Example:*

```
library(ordinal)

## clmm -- doesn't work
fmm1 <- clmm(rating ~ temp + contact + (1|judge), data = wine)
predict(fmm1)
# Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
#   no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "clmm"
ordinal:::predict.clm(fmm1)
# Error in get_clmDesign(fullmf = object, terms.list = terms.list, contrasts = contrasts) : 
#   all(sapply(terms.list, inherits, "terms")) is not TRUE

## clmm2 -- works!
fmm2 <- clmm2(rating ~ temp + contact, random=judge, data = wine)   
predict(fmm2)
# [1] 0.41952700 0.47195487 0.55026797 ...
ordinal:::predict.clm2(fmm2)
# [1] 0.41952700 0.47195487 0.55026797 ...

stopifnot(all.equal((fmm1$coefficients), fmm2$coefficients[-7], tol=10e-6))
```

(PS: Referring to `ordinal` version 2019.12-10 and R version 4.0.0)

Comment: Thank you for your response - I don't think I can use clmm2() because I don't see where it can accommodate for nested random effects.

Comment: @HannahMiriamDancy I see. I just saw that this has already been issued: https://github.com/runehaubo/ordinal/issues/20

Comment: @HannahMiriamDancy Perhaps you will find some alternatives here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238675/163114

Comment: Thank you for your help - it's unfortunate to see that it has not been addressed, especially seeing the forum post you linked is from almost a year ago. I've been trying mixor out, which is being...difficult, and will look at MCMCglmm and brms as well.

Comment: Welcome @HannahMiriamDancy. I don't know if its worth to bump the issue in github. Good luck with the alternatives, feel free to publish an alternative here if you are successful!

Comment: If I find an alternative, I will definitely update. Thank you again.

Comment: Does anyone have an update about getting predictions from clmm?