# source code for grow function in randomForest R package

Tags: r, random-forest

In source code of R `randomForest` package, I find the following code in `grow.R`. What's the purpose for `UseMethod`? Why does function `grow` not have function definition and just `grow.default` and `grow.randomForest` have definition? Is this something related to calling C function in the R package?

```
grow <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("grow")

grow.default <- function(x, ...)
  stop("grow has not been implemented for this class of object")

grow.randomForest <- function(x, how.many, ...) {
  y <- update(x, ntree=how.many)
  combine(x, y)
}
```

Also, in the `randomForest.R` file, I only find the following code. There is `randomForest.default.R` file too. Why is there no `randomForest.randomForest` definition like function `grow`?

```
"randomForest" <-
function(x, ...)
  UseMethod("randomForest")
```

Comment: Are you familiar with S3 classes? Reading a little bit about S3 dispatch would be a good place to start. [Advanced R has a section on S3](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html).

Comment: There's nothing in the code you show that has anything to do with calling C code. Why the authors chose to make the `grow()` default an error and the `randomForest` default the main method is hard to answer definitively. Presumably they wanted `grow()` to error early if it gets called on inappropriate input, but still keep it flexible to work with other classes.

Comment: There's no `randomForest.randomForest` method because you don't use a `randomForest` object as **input** to the `randomForest()` function. But they do use S3 dispatch to handle formula and (default) matrix, and you can see the `randomForest.default` and `randomForest.formula` code in their respective files.

Comment: @BenBolker <<sigh>> okay, written up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the purpose for UseMethod? Why does function grow not have function definition and just `grow.default` and `grow.randomForest` have definition?

I'd suggest reading about S3 dispatch to understand the patterns you see. [Advanced R has a chapter on S3](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html). You can also see [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6583265/903061) here [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function/19226817#19226817).

> Is this something related to calling C function in the R package?

No.

> Why is there no `randomForest.randomForest` definition like function grow?

This should make sense if you do the recommended reading above. S3 dispatch uses a pattern of `function_name.class` to call the correct version of the function (*method*) based on class of the input. You don't give a `randomForest` object as an input to the `randomForest` function, so there is no `randomForest.randomForest` method defined.

`grow()` does get called on `randomForest` objects, hence the `grow.randomForest()` method. Presumably the authors wanted `grow()` to error early if it gets called on inappropriate input, so the default for other classes is an immediate error, but they still keep dispatch flexible to work with other classes, enabling extensions of the package and nice play with other packages that may have their own `grow()` implementations.