# Differences between anova(), anova.rq(), anova.rqs(), and anova.rqlist()

Tags: r, anova, quantile-regression, quantreg

The `quantreg` package introduces functions related to the computations of quantile regression models. Among the additional functions, we have the titular `anova.rq()`, `anova.rqs()`, and `anova.rqlist()`.

However, `?anova.rqs()` and `?anova.rqlist()` refer to the description of the `anova.rq()` function: "Compute test statistics for two or more quantile regression fits."

**What are the differences between the mentioned functions?**
From what I read, the application of `anova()` alone to evaluate quantile regression models tests whether the slope coefficients of the examined models can be considered not different across chosen quantiles. For example:

```
library(quantreg)
n <- 1000  
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(n, 0, 1),  # Normal distribution for x1
  x2 = runif(n, -1, 1),  # Uniform distribution for x2
  y = 2 + 1.5 * rnorm(n, 0, 1) + runif(n, -1, 1)  # Linear combination with noise for y
)

model1 <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2, tau = 0.25, data = df)
model2 <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2, tau = 0.5, data = df)
```

In such a situation, **both** `anova(model1, model2)` and `anova.rq(model1, model2)` respectively provide the following answers:

```
Quantile Regression Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: y ~ x1 + x2
Joint Test of Equality of Slopes: tau in {  0.25 0.5  }

  Df Resid Df F value Pr(>F)
1  2     1998   0.346 0.7075
```

(in this case, the slope coefficients do not differ in those selected quantiles).

However, in the case:

```
> anova.rqs(model1, model2)
Error in object$coefficients[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions
> anova.rqlist(model1, model2)
Error in formula.default(x) : invalid formula
```

If we make some changes in the models:

```
model1 <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2, tau = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), data = df)
model2 <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2, tau = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), data = df)
```

and run the functions:

```
> anova(model1, model2)
Quantile Regression Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: y ~ x1 + x2
Joint Test of Equality of Slopes: tau in {  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  }

  Df Resid Df F value Pr(>F)
1 16     8984  0.9169  0.549
> anova.rq(model1, model2)
Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
> anova.rqs(model1, model2)
Quantile Regression Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: y ~ x1 + x2
Joint Test of Equality of Slopes: tau in {  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  }

  Df Resid Df F value Pr(>F)
1 16     8984  0.9169  0.549
> anova.rqlist(model1, model2)
Error in formula.default(x) : invalid formula
```

Thus, I have the impression that `anova()` is significantly more versatile than `anova.rq()` and `anova.rqs()`. However, I am unsure when `anova.rqlist()` might be useful.

Comment: `anova` is a _generic_ function, which means that the specific method dispatched depends on the object you give it. A specific _method_ for the `anova` method will be specified by a period followed by the name of the class of object to which it is applied. In R this is known as the S3 object-oriented method. See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583265/what-does-s3-methods-mean-in-r